# The $S^1$ action on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: differential-geometry, group-actions, vector-fields

I'm reading some lecture notes which discuss in a part of it some examples of the circle actions on manifolds. I hope that someone help me to understand the following:

> Let $M$ be a a manifold provided with an action of the 1-sphere $S^1$ by a group of transformations with a parameter $g(\theta)$. We denote $J$ the vector field on $M$  defined by
> $$ (Jf)(x)= -\frac{d}{d\theta} {f(g(\theta)x)}_{\theta=0}, \qquad f \in C^\infty(M).$$

- Consider the action of $S^1$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ by rotations. Why in this case the vector field $J$ is given by :
  $$J = x_2 \partial_1 - x_1 \partial_2 ? $$
- what is the importance  of the vector field $J$, I mean what are the informations it gives us about the circle action ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are asking for in the first bullet point... Are you asking how to derive the formula $J = x_2 \partial_1 - x_1 \partial_2$ from the information given, which would include a formula for $g(\theta)$? If so, what I would say is: substitute $J = x_2 \partial_1 - x_1 \partial_2$ on the left hand side, substitute the formula for $g$ on the right hand side; and check that you get an equation.

Comment: @Lee Mosher, I'm asking how to obtain  this formula  $J = x_2 \partial_1 - x_1\partial_2$ in the special case when $ M =\mathbb{R}^2$ is provided by  the action of  $S^1$ by rotations: by multiplication by the matrix $\begin {pmatrix} cos \theta & -sin \theta \\ sin \theta & \cos \theta \end {pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lee Mosher points out, your first bullet is solvable via direct calculation.  You know what $g(\theta)$ is (it's the rotation matrix), so you know what the function $g(\theta)x$ is.  Now write down the derivative of $f(g(\theta)x)$ using the chain rule, substitute $\theta=0$, and write the end result as $(\text{differential operator})f$.

The second bullet is a more worthy question.

Consider the circle acting on itself and the function $\exp{}\in S^1\to\mathbb{R}$.  An action of $S^1$ shifts points in $S^1$…which multiplies the exponential of those points by a constant.  So rather than talk about shifting points in $S^1$, we can talk about multiplying exponentials by a constant, and this is (in some sense) the same action.  Of course, the same holds true for any function on $S^1$, not just exponentials; just the resulting action is much more complicated in that case.

More generally, your circle action on $M$ also gives a circle action on $M\to\mathbb{R}$ (as well as higher-regularity subspaces): rather than moving your points, you move the observables instead.  $J$ is the *infinitesimal generator* of this dual action.  That is, the effect of an angle $\theta$ on those functions is given by $\exp{(-\theta J)}$, where the exponential is in the sense of Lie theory.  The intuition is that if $S^1$ were instead a finite cyclic group, generated by $g$, then each action is given by repeated actions of $g$; similarly, here the $S^1$ action is given by repeating a tiny neighborhood of $0\in S^1$.

To be precise: for all $\theta$ and $x$, $$\frac{d}{d\theta}f(g(\theta)x)=-(Jf)(x)$$  Thus for all $\theta$ and $\phi$, $$\frac{d}{d\theta}f(g(\theta+\phi)x)=\frac{d}{d\theta}f(g(\theta)g(\phi)x)=-(Jf)(g(\phi)x)$$  The only solution to this partial differential equation (with $x$ as the "spatial" variable and $\theta$ as "time") is $\exp{(-\theta J)}f$.

Comment: thank you so much Jacob ! this is exactly the kind of explanation I was looking for ! Could you please just calrify the point when you say that " ...the effect of an angle $\theta$ on those functions is given by $exp(\theta J)$ " ? I know what the exponential map in Lie theory is, but can't see why it appears in this situation ?

Comment: @asma: Done, I guess.

Comment: Yes it is, thanks a lot for your time and your help @Jacob